# Header is not responding in my php code

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing the code for an html form (using bootstrap) and when all is said and done (input validation + adding successfully to database) I want to go back to the main page (main.php).

Here is the code for newtask.php (I've included comments instead of code, for simplicity)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nueva tarea</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/thestyle.css" rel="stylesheet">

  /Some scripts 

</head>

<body>

    <!----------------------Checking rights------------------------>
    <?php include 'rights.php'?>

    <!-------------------Top navigation bar---------------- -->

    <!--------------- DB queries for some select fields in the form------------------->

    <!---------------------- The FORM itself --------------------------->

    <!-----------------------Validate the input ------------------------------>
    <?php include 'validate.php' ?>

    <!----------------------- Add an entry a DB table------------------------------>
    <?php include 'addtask.php' ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code addtask.php

```
<?php

  function changeDateFormat($input){ 
    $list = explode('/',$input);
    $newdate = $list[2] . '-' . $list[1] . '-' . $list[0];
    return $newdate;
  }    

  //Check if the form was validated
  if ($validated == 0){
      exit();
  }

  // Create connection
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","task_user","task","tasks");

  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "No se puede conectar a la base de datos: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else{
    //Adding a new task.

    //Getting username ID.
    $userid = $_SESSION["user_key_id"];
    $name = $_POST["thename"];
    $description = $_POST["desc"];
    $start_date = changeDateFormat($_POST["date_s"]); 
    $update_date = changeDateFormat($_POST["date_u"]);
    $status = $_POST["states"];
    $percent = $_POST["percent"]; 
    $proyect = $_POST["proyect"];

    //Getting the project ID number.
    $sqlquery="SELECT name,keyid FROM proyects WHERE name IN ('$proyect')";    
    $name_key_pair=mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery);
    $proyect = mysqli_fetch_array($name_key_pair)['keyid'];

    $sqlquery = "INSERT INTO tasks (proyect,start_date,update_date,description,status,percent,user,name) VALUES ('$proyect','$start_date','$update_date','$description','$status','$percent','$userid','$name')";    
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery)){
      echo '<h3><label> ERROR en el query: ' . mysqli_error($con) . '</label></h3>';
    }
    else{
      mysqli_close($con);
      header("location:main.php");
    }
  }

?>
```

I've used an ECHO to verify that the code does get to the header. Also phpmyadmin to verify that the entry IS added to the DB. Also this uses a user login system. the user login uses the same header command to send the user to main.php after the user has successfully logged in.

Can any one tell me why the header is not working in this particular case?

Just to clarify what happens is that when the user submits the form he stays in newtask.php instead of going to main.php. If I try to go there from the navigation bar, I get to main.php with no problems.

Comment: Because you must not send **any** output before the `Location` header. But here you have already displayed half a webpage before even trying to add the user. The documentation of [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is pretty clear, and you should have read it since you are having problems with that function.

Comment: ob_start() and ob_end_flush()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers only can send before the first output is made (In UTF-8 Bom would be an output).

You should develop according to the input, process, output principe.

- So first you should get your input (`$_POST`, `$_GET`) and save this to your Objects and Variables.
- Then Process the input (calculation,saving etc...)
- Now it is a good time to send headers,
- Final display the data.

This is a basic principe, where you should starting. More complex is something like `MVC`.

A Quick fix would be to use an output buffer, which can be easly achieved via [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_end_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) methods.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not allow you to output anything to browser before setting headers. So, if you have HTML code before the header function call you need to either refactor your code so that you can set headers before anything is written to output stream or you can control your outputting with [Output Control Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

Answer (score 1):

Headers must be empty for redirects to work

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

Answer (score 0):

```
@ob_end_clean();
header("location:main.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add an alternative. I've upvoted several of the answers because it was obvious that I wans't understanding header properly. Take into account than I knew nothing about web technologies a week ago. So I have off moments like this. Any ways, even though I understood somewhat the concept of output buffering I could not find a way to use it properly (again, probably due to inexperience). But I did find an alternative that works for me, for now. I've called a JavaScript function that just redirects me to my main page. Like this:

Instead of the header command (addtask.php), I used this line:

```
echo '<script type = "text/javascript"> goToMain(); </script>';
```

then in newtask.php I added this in the head section:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    function goToMain(){
      window.location="main.php";
    } 
  </script>
```

This works. I'm sure there is something not OK about this (because no one proposed it, although I would like to know why, if any one can bother) but it seems simpler for now. Because of this I'm not voting this as the correct answer but rather Christian Gollhardt, because it seemed the most informative.